# Not getting proper crash information using Flurry

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports, flurry, symbolicatecrash

I have integrated Flurry 4.3 SDK in my app, also uploaded the correct Desym file. I not getting the object and method call info for crashes in some cases, but i am getting them in other cases.

This is what i am getting in some cases.

`17  MyApp  0x0009744f __mh_execute_header + 394319`

I have added the following lines in app delegate.

```
[Flurry setCrashReportingEnabled:YES];
    [Flurry startSession:kFlurryAppKey];
```

Please help me out in resolving this, as i am not getting the full readable stack trace.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  We're seeing something pretty similar.

Comment: why don't you try crashlytics provide by Fabric.